# Regarding fonts and font spacing, what is the difference between Optical kerning in Adobe and font-optical-sizing sizing in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, adobe, adobe-illustrator

Confusingly, CSS and Adobe have similar names to what I believe are two very different concepts.

In Adobe, when you choose a font, you have a couple options when it comes to Kerning rules Auto, Optical, Metric-Roman.

In CSS, there is a rule which can be expressed thusly:

```
font-optical-sizing: auto;
font-optical-sizing: none;
```

The Optical font sizing done by Illustrator is done via this [algorithm](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5803629).

However, in CSS, I don't believe that this spacing is done algorithmically.  In this article written for the Google fonts team, they describe Optical sizing as "the practice of type foundries creating slightly different versions of a typeface intended to be used at different sizes. Generally speaking, small (body or caption) optical sizes tend to have less stroke contrast, larger x-heights, wider characters, and more open spacing. - Elliot Jay Stacks".  Full article [here](https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/choosing_type/choosing_typefaces_that_have_optical_sizes).

The important thing to note in the CSS description is that it is something that type foundries add *themselves.*

Can somebody confirm that these two are, in fact, two separate and very different things.

Comment: As I understand it CSS font-optical-sizing is to do with individual characters and how to render them best at different sizes (ie no just scale them but alter some of their characteristics). Kerning on the other hand is concerned with getting the way letters lie next to each other to be in some way ‘optimal’ for the human eye. I do not believe these two things are the same, they just have the word optical in them, but of course the design of a typeface at a particular size may affect the way you’d like kerning to happen for some ‘optimal’ layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Optical font sizing done by Illustrator is done via this algorithm.

The terminology in the question is getting mixed up: that is optical *kerning*, not optical *sizing*.

> .. similar names to what I believe are two very different concepts.

The only similarity is that both have "optical", but they are very different concepts and would well understood by typographers.

*Kerning* has to do with adjusting the spacing between glyphs so that the spacing across a line is more consistent. A representative example is the letter pair AV, and TA is another good example. Compare these:

[image: two text samples with the word tavern]

In the first, there's too much space between T and A, and too much between A and V. In the second, these pairs are kerned to reduce the space. (Quickly done example isn't perfect but illustrates the point.)

*Optical* kerning would be understood to mean an algorithm for setting kerning adjustments using an automated analysis of shapes.

Optical sizing is completely different. The term is used but isn't really an accurate description of the process—no *size adjustment* is being done.

Rather, it has to do with the fact that some font families are crafted with different glyphs intended for use and different text sizes. The Google Fonts article is explaining just that. For example, in the following figure the four lines are samples from the same font family intended for use at different sizes.

[image: four text samples of the word text showing differences in the design of corresponding glyphs]

The four fonts are intended for use at different sizes, but they are scaled to the same size to make the differences in the design more noticeable. The first is intended for use at large text sizes and has fine details such as the thin serifs and significant change (modulation) in the width of the round stroke in the letter e. But if you scaled that font down to a small size, for body text or captions, then those details would be lost, and the glyphs would become less legible. Also, the spacing between glyphs would get too tight, further hindering legibility. So, for smaller sizes, variants of the font are created to trade off some of the details of the design to improve legibility.

These kinds of typeface variants within a font family are referred to by typographers as *optical sizes*, and a font family that includes such variants might be referred to as an *optical size family* or as *having optical sizes*.

[Adobe’s *Kepler*](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/kepler) family is an example of a family with optical sizes. Note that most of the 168 fonts within the family have an extra descriptor at the end of the name: "Caption", "Display", "Subhead": those are variants of the design intended for very small size text ("Caption"), very large size text, such as titles ("Display"), and somewhat large—larger than body text ("Subhead")

In CSS, when font-optical-sizing is set to auto, if the selected family has optical size variants, then the browser will automatically select the specific optical variant based on the font-size property value.

This feature in CSS is tied to the introduction of OpenType Font Variations six years ago. Back in the days of metal type, it was very common for type to have optical size variants. When scalable photo-typesetting was invented in the mid twentieth century (type designed on film, clear with a black mask, then used to expose photographic plates), the same design started being used for all sizes, and typography quality in general regressed. Scalable digital type continued that trend: Some optical size type (e.g., Adobe Kepler) was still available, but most fonts did not have optical size variants. With the advent of variable fonts in OpenType, however, optical size variants are making a strong comeback.

The font-optical-sizing property was added to CSS in 2017/2018 when support for variable fonts was also added.

So, both terms include "optical", but they are indeed very different concepts.

Comment: Thank you Peter - what an excellent answer.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Please do not discuss patents.

Comment: Peter - this could be a separate question but are you aware of whether Optical kerning done in Illustrator via algorithm has a CSS equivalent? My hunch is that the answer is no.

Comment: To be supported in CSS, it has to be supportable in all browsers. This sounds like a proprietary Adobe algorithm. Not surprisingly, I don't see anything like this in CSS.

Comment: What CSS does provide is the [font-kerning](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#font-kerning-prop) property. One of the values defined is `auto`, which means that the browser can use its own criteria to decide _whether_ to enable kerning. But it doesn't appear to be intended that the browser can decide _how_ kerning is done: "This property controls metric kerning, kerning that utilizes adjustment data contained in the font."

Comment: The data in the font can take one of two forms. The legacy ['kern' table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/kern) was part of the original TrueType spec and can be used to list specific glyph pairs and the spacing adjustment for each. Size-wise, it's not very efficient.

Comment: A newer approach was introduced in the OpenType spec: the ['kern' feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_ko#tag-kern) (or the ['vkrn' feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_uz#tag-vkrn) for vertical layout) can be used to activate metric adjustment actions in the ['GPOS' (glyph positioning) table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gpos). In the GPOS table, positioning actions can be specified for sets of glyphs that require the same metric adjustments.

Comment: The GPOS table supports several different types of positioning actions. (In the OpenType spec, these are referred to as "lookup tables".) When using a GPOS table with the 'kern' feature, typically the font developer would implement using [pair positioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gpos#lookup-type-2-pair-adjustment-positioning-subtable) actions.

Comment: Whether the browser is utilizing a 'kern' table in the font or activating a GPOS 'kern' feature, how much spacing is adjusted for any glyph pair is specified in the font with data provided by the font developer. Adobe's "optical kerning" is using an algorithm that examples the shapes of glyphs to decide how much to adjust spacing for a given glyph pair rather than relying on 'kern' or GPOS data in the font.

Comment: Thank you Peter - really appreciate your answer here in the comments.  I'd love to give you credit on Stackoverflow - I made a separate question where you can copy and paste your comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74047798/does-optical-kerning-in-in-adobe-have-a-css-equivalent